# Split php varibale with JS into array

Tags: javascript, php, html, split

I have tried everything and I can not split a PHP variable into two parts so I can insert them into two input fields. I have read numerous topics here and I don't see the problem...

This peace of code gives me a result that php variable is inserted into a wanted filed.

Lets say the PHP variable is data1-data2:

```
  document.hiderad.selectstate.onchange = updateText;

function updateText() {
    var str = document.hiderad.selectstate;
    document.hiderad.opis.value = str.value;
}
```

Code above inserted data1-data2 into wanted HTML input.

And soon as i try to split it i get undefined warning. I have tried 7 different things to approach this problem so i want even list all the versions I tried. Can someone please help?

```
document.hiderad.selectstate.onchange = updateText;
function updateText() {
    var str = document.hiderad.selectstate;
    var array = str.toString().split('-');
    a = array[0], b = array[1];
    document.hiderad.opis.value = a.value;
    document.hiderad.iznos.value = b.value;
}
```

Code above gives me b undefined  if i remove last line i get a undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `a.value` and `b.value`, that's for getting the value of an input field, not a string. You should use that to get the value of the `selectstate` input.

Also, always declare local variables unless you have a specific reason to assign global variables.

```
function updateText() {
    var str = document.hiderad.selectstate;
    var array = str.value.split('-');
    var a = array[0], b = array[1];
    document.hiderad.opis.value = a;
    document.hiderad.iznos.value = b;
}
```

Comment: Now when I see is like this it makes sense. I was looking at it for too long. Thank you for the help.